# How to count by attribute in JSON?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",           
      "name": "John",
      "location": {
        "town": {
          "id": "10"
        },
        "address": "600 Fake Street",
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-01-19",
      "last_modified_date": "2017-05-18"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",           
      "name": "Sarah",
      "location": {
        "town": {
          "id": "10"
        },
        "address": "76 Evergreen Street",
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-01-19",
      "last_modified_date": "2017-05-18"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",           
      "name": "Hamed",
      "location": {
        "town": {
          "id": "20"
        },
        "address": "50 East A Street",
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-01-19",
      "last_modified_date": "2017-05-18"
    }    
  ]
}
```

And I need to get something like this, count how many times each `townId` appears:

```
[ { "10": 2 }, {"20": 1 }]
```

I'm trying to find the most eficient way to do this. Any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: Not necessarily, but perhaps this is meant to be a JavaScript question?

Comment: Hi. No, is a Java one.

Comment: So, use your favourite json parser to read the file into data structure, then walk through the structure counting whatever data you deem worth to be counted.

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient way is to load the String in a StringBuilder and remove all line breaks and white spaces. Then search for index of `"town":{"id":"` string (town start index) and then search for the end index (String `"}'). Using the 2 indexes you can extract town ids and count them.

No need to deserialize the JSON into POJO objects:) and extract values by xpath from the POJOs.